# php zipArchive on Google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

The project that i am working on requires files to be zipped.

The project is hosted on google app engine php runtime

I am not able to use the php zipArchive.

Is it allowed on google app engine?

Answer (score 2):

The zip extension was added in the [1.8.9](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) App Engine release.

Comment: Seems like the current version of GAE has a bug preventing writing a zip file to storage. I'm having the same problem as described here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145099/google-app-engine-php-zip-extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145099/google-app-engine-php-zip-extension)

Answer (score 0):

Check here for the enabled extensions for GAE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#Extensions

Though it doesn't look like they have it enabled.

Comment: seems like .zip is not enanbled... is there any other way to zip audio files on GAE

Comment: It looks like this information has moved to a different url: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/runtime#enabled_extensions