# Extract using php on google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine

How can I extract a zip file using php running on google app engine. I tried the ZipArchive class but it gives a class not found exception on google app engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like ZipArchive is not in the list of enabled extensions.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Enabled_extensions

[php zipArchive on Google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18015773/php-ziparchive-on-google-app-engine)

This doesn't require an extension, but if it is pure php it will not be as fast.  I haven't tried it, but it's worth a shot.
http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/

Answer (score 0):

For newer readers of this question - the zip extension was added in the App Engine [1.8.9](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkReleaseNotes) release.