# Google app engine php zip extension

Tags: php, google-app-engine, php-ziparchive

I am using Google app engine and I want to create a zip archive using the zip extension which is supported in the current version. The problem is that every time i call ZipArchive::close it returns false and ZipArchive::getStatusString returns "Failure to create temporary file: Read-only file system". I am creating the zip file in the cloud storage like this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$zip->open("gs://whatever/somethig.zip", ZipArchive::OVERWRITE); //returns true
$zip->addFromString('file.txt', "some random data"); //returns true
$zip->numFiles; // = 1
$zip->close(); // returns false
$zip->getStatusString(); //returns Failure to create temporary file: Read-only file system
```

and it should be writable, it actually is with file_set_content or whatever. I tried the same code with a couple of variations:

1. already existing zip file;
2. not existing zip file;
3. ZipArchive::CREATE as a second parameter of the ZipArchive::open call
4. Using ZipArchive::addFile to add the file from cloud storage

Maybe it tries to create a temporary file on some other place not on the cloud storage, but this thing that i'm doing is very common scenario and i doubt that this is an app engine bug, after all they claim that they support the zip extension [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/#PHP_Enabled_extensions).

Does someone have some idea what can be the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug - can you open an issue in the [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3)?

Comment: I've opened [an issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11010&thanks=11010&ts=1402415512)

Comment: I'm having issues extracting Zip files on GS :(

Comment: I get "Invalid Argument" for the above code when trying this on the dev app engine server. Any updates on how to fix this?